# How to get Sum of Measure value in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

was wondering if anyone knows how I can get the **sum of a measure** in Power BI. I have googled and tried different methods the entire day but it still doesn't work.

The table below shows my Measure, `Resources divided by Count of Date 3`, which equates to the number of resources per day =

```
DIVIDE(
    SUM('table'[Resource]),
    DISTINCTCOUNT('table'[Date])
)
```

However, now i want to get the sum of this measure i.e. get the sum of resources for the selected week but its not showing up correctly:

[image]

The total value should show up as **60.11** instead of **53.25**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make this into an iterative measure:

```
Additive Measure =
SUMX (
    VALUES ( 'table'[Parent_Project_Type] ), 
    [Your existing measure]
)
```

OR with your new table name information:

```
SUMX (
    VALUES ( as_mapops_resource_management[Parent_Project_Type] ), 
    [resource date level] // Note: this is a measure reference
)
```

Comment: thanks Marcus! I tried that already but it doesnt work sadly. This is what i got: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pAFIDsV-saukmNkbl4ObbqlaTGoLnWRI/view?usp=share_link

Comment: I don't really see how your solution is different than what I suggested, apart from being more verbose. `VALUES` gives you the same as `SUMMARIZE` over a single column. Does the (edited, with table information) measure I have suggested does not work?

Comment: Note: The original suggestion has [your existing measure], but if you pasted your measure *code* there, you would also need to wrap this in `CALCULATE` to enable the required context transition for correct calculation!

Comment: hey, you're right! that's weird it didnt work earlier...will mark it as accepted ans! thanks Marcus!!

Comment: Glad it works as expected! I am in parental leave and I thought I might be losing it.. :-)

Comment: Sorry, my bad you're still good

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out another solution alternative to what Marcus shared. Also noted the final value should be **69.45** instead of **60.11** as stated above. Missed out one category when doing manual calculation..

Posting my solution here for anyone who needs it:

```
Additive Measure = 
SUMX( SUMMARIZE(table, table[Parent_Project_Type]), [resource date level])
```

[image]